# jQueryUI position() breaks events

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, hover, jquery-events

I don't know if its me but I'm having some problem with the `position()` utility from jQueryui.

Sometimes, when a element is positioned with jQuery ui, the events on it don't work any more!

It's totally strange that happens only on certain elements but I can't find a common point.

I have some buttons on which I want to change the background on hover:

```
<div  class="hidden" id="context">
    <div class="move up"><span></span></div>
    <div class="move down"><span></span></div>
    <div class="move left"><span></span></div>
    <div class="move right"><span></span></div>
</div>
```

her's the css:

```
    div.move {
    position: absolute;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: #333 0px -3px 1px inset, white 0px 2px 1px inset, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0px 3px 5px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

div.move span{
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.1s linear;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-box-shadow: #333 0px -3px 1px inset, white 0px 2px 1px inset;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

div.move span:hover{
    opacity: 0; 
}

div.move.left span{
    background: url(images/left1.png) no-repeat;    
}

div.move.left{
    background: url(images/left-hover.png) no-repeat;
[...]
```

and finally the js:

```
        $('div.move.left').position({
            of: $('td.grid.current'),
            my: 'center center',
            at: 'left center',
            offset: '-40px 0',
            collision:  'none'
        });
```

Even if I use jQuery events it doesn't work!

Does anyone have any solution?

EDIT: maybe I got it and seems to be a bug!

Once the app run it generates html in the `#context` container, creating main table and small tables for every td of the main one:

```
<div class="" id="context">
    <div class="move up" style="top: -60px; left: 505px; "><span></span></div>
    <div class="move down" style="top: 780px; left: 505px; "><span></span></div>
    <div class="move left" style="top: 360px; left: -20px; "><span></span></div>
    <div class="move right" style="top: 360px; left: 1069px; "><span></span></div>
    <table class="grids" style="position: relative; top: -618px; left: -539px; ">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="gridsRow">
                <td class="grid current">
                    <div class="id">0</div>
                    <div class="gridTotal"></div>
                    <div class="close"><span class="hover"></span></div>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="cellsRow">
                                <td class="cell current">
                                    <div class="id">0</div>
                                    <label>0</label>
                                </td>
                                [...]
                            
</div>
```

All the elements that have positions styled inline have been processed by the `position()` function of jQuery ui. The main table **table.grids** is moved by this code:

```
    $('table.grids').position({
        my: 'left top',
        at: 'center center',
        of: $('#context'),
        offset: '-1064px -998px'
    });
```

Ok, the problem is this piece of code.

**If I move table.grids using `position()` the events handling on the .move buttons is disabled**

If I delete this code the problem disappear.
I think it's a sort of bug.
I thought that maybe the bug appear if you `position()` an element against a child of a another `position()`ed element. But the stranger is that if **I `position()` any other element against `td.grid.current` the bug doesn't show up**! it happens only with the `.move` buttons!

Here I give some insight about the appn:

> First I'll explain how my app works.
> It's a system I thought of to help me
> counting cells on mouse brain slices
> colored with immuno-enzymatic
> reaction.
>
> On the screen you have a grid
> (**td.grid**) in which you put the
> number of cells. this grid is itself
> part of a bigger table
> (**table.grids**) that contains many
> small grids. Once one small grid is
> full I want to switch to the grids
> nearby using direction buttons
> (move.up for example) that move away
> from the current grid
> (**td.grid.current**) to the next one.
>
> I used jQuery ui position to fix the
> td.grid.current on the center of he
> page even if you resize it, by fixing
> the position of the main table
> (table.grids) with a certain offset to
> center on the grid. and then i used
> position() also to fix the buttons
> relatively to the current grid.

Comment: im not sure you are using position correctly. It seems position just gets the position relative to the parent. This would be something like the left or right attributes in css where the div has relative positioning. Offset gets the position from the entire frame or window. I really don't see what you are trying to accomplish. Maybe post a working example what you want to do on jsfiddle.

Comment: ehm, this is a part of a [desktop]webapp that is quite big, would be a bit complicate to post all of it! Hwr the position() of jqueryUI is a method to facilitate dinamic positioning (especially centering) of a element against another. for example my code set the element div.move.left to have its center (my:) fit the left center (at:) of the element td.grid.current (of:)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to move around the div, use
`$('div.move.left').css();` or `$('div.move.left').animate();`

`.position()` doesn't take any arguments.

**Documentation:**
`.css();` - http://api.jquery.com/css/
`.position();` - http://api.jquery.com/position/
`.animate();` - http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: ehm, actually it does, if it is the one from jquery UI. http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/

Comment: @Bakaburg: Ah sorry, though we were working with just jQuery here.